# Search commands in history with discontinuous keywords

Tags: bash, command-history, search

I was wondering how to  search commands in history without knowing the first few letters of the command?

When searching using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in `bash`, one has to give the first few letters of the command. What if I only know some characters in the middle, or some at the beginning and some in the middle?

For example, to search `cat myfile`, I only know there is `at` in it, or `c` at the beginning and `my` in the middle somewhere. keywords have to be continuously positioned. For example, in `cat myfile`, I would like to search for both`c` and `my`, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will not allow to specify both simultaneously.

Comment: I use Ctrl-R all the time and it searches the middle text automatically. Nothing fancy, but in your example just typing `my` would be sufficient. RHEL4 and Cygwin confirmed.

Comment: @Tim: you didn't actually try that, right?  Because it *does* search for letters in the middle of a command.

Comment: @alex: I actually wanted to say keywords that are not continously positioned. For example, in `cat myfile`, I would like to search for both`c` and `my`, but Ctrl+R will not allow to specify both simultaneously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are just looking to find the line (to jog your memory) you could just grep for the part of the command you remember:

```
history | grep "substring"
```

Comment: How is it that I've been using *nix systems for 5+ years and didn't know about the `history` command until now? Thanks!

Comment: @GMA Pedantically, it isn’t a command, it is a shell builtin, equivalent to the [POSIX `fc` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) run with the `-l` (list) argument.

Comment: Note that on zsh, `history` only returns the last couple of entries. To search in your entire history, use `history 0 | grep "substring"`

Answer (score 12):

Bash only has a simple string search, as far as I can see.

Consider switching to [zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/zsh/info), which has a history wildcard search. [`history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-history_002dincremental_002dpattern_002dsearch_002dbackward) and [`history-incremental-pattern-search-forward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-history_002dincremental_002dpattern_002dsearch_002dforward) aren't bound to keys by default, but you can bind them:

```
bindkey '^X^R' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
bindkey '^X^S' history-incremental-pattern-search-forward
```

Then type `Ctrl+X Ctrl+R ^c*my`.

Answer (score -1):

Apropos(1) should also return a man for the subject if the man contains that word. Whatis(1) returns only absolute matches.

For reference:
Apropos == man -k
Whatis == man -f

These two should be a great help, along with wildcards * and ?

Comment: The question is about searching through the command history in the *terminal*... (not searching the man pages)... but on a completely seperate note, I did find your answer useful, so +1 :)

Comment: ....Ah lovely, my bad on that one mate.